# Are VPNs useless if end point countries have data retention laws

Tags: privacy, vpn

If I establish a VPN from my PC (in Australia, say) to a foreign VPN server (say in UK) then my ISP will see a single connection and can retain this information.

This foreign VPN server will be connected to an ISP which, for question sake, is also subject to UK data retention laws.

If these two countries cooperated, is it straightforward to correlate packets sent and received to determine what sites I browse over this VPN?

Comment: Data retention laws are not a prerequisite for correlation. And to determine what you browse, correlation is not required at all, just a request to the cooperating VPN provider.

Comment: If you want strong privacy, use a VPN in a jurisdiction without retention laws. It's not fair to say a VPN is useless in this case, they still have benefits, e.g. stopping someone on the same WiFi seeing your traffic.

Comment: @paj28, I am referring to situation of usefulness of concealing traffic from governments. VPNs for concealing traffic from local parties, fellow coffee drinkers, your ISP, and anyone else monitoring path to VPN terminal still has usefulness as you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is often fairly straight-forwards to correlate the requests if someone considers it important enough. Rather depends on what you are doing though.

If you wanted to make it harder, you should use the most commonly used VPN service possible (helps hide traffic in the noise) and connect via ToR. Of course, that would probably be totally unusable if you wanted to watch the latest episode of East Enders on the BBC ;-)

Even then, that wouldn't be safe if someone suspected that it was you connected to something because then they could still track the origin (you) and the end-point. There have been a number of high-profile take-downs using this method.

Comment: TORoVPN or VPNoTOR?

Comment: Probably VPN to ToR since you probably have to sign-up to a VPN which might make it easier to track that part. All you are really doing is trying to make it a bit harder to join the dots.